# C (Preprocessor): How to concatenate/append substitution string

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I define my exceptions on the command line:

```
-DEXCEPTION_1=\"first\" -DEXCEPTION_2=\"second\" -DEXCEPTION_3=\"third\"
```

which I check against a string:

```
except = 0;
#ifdef EXCEPTION_1
if (! strcmp(EXCEPTION_1, mystring))
{  except = 1;
}
#endif
#ifdef EXCEPTION_2
if (! strcmp(EXCEPTION_2, mystring))
{  except = 1;
}
#endif
#ifdef EXCEPTION_3
if (! strcmp(EXCEPTION_3, mystring))
{  except = 1;
}
#endif
if (except == 1)
{  // do something
}
else
{  // do something else
}
```

Needless to say, while this works, it is also quite ugly, inflexible and causes redundancy in my code.

Is there a way to append a string to a preprocessor macro variable?

I would like to get something like this (the problem of course is that `#append` does not exist):

```
#ifdef EXCEPTION_1 #append EXCEPTIONS if (! strcmp(EXCEPTION_1, mystring)) {  except = 1; }
#ifdef EXCEPTION_2 #append EXCEPTIONS if (! strcmp(EXCEPTION_2, mystring)) {  except = 1; }
#ifdef EXCEPTION_3 #append EXCEPTIONS if (! strcmp(EXCEPTION_3, mystring)) {  except = 1; }
```

Then I could just use `EXCEPTIONS` in the code and it would work with all possible permutations of exceptions.

In other words I want to append a string to a macro variable - is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have chains of defines, but it won't look much better:

```
#ifdef EXCEPTION_1 
#define EXCEPTIONS1 if (! strcmp(EXCEPTION_1, mystring)) {  except = 1; }
#else
#define EXCEPTIONS1
#endif

#ifdef EXCEPTION_2
#define EXCEPTIONS2 EXCEPTIONS1 if (! strcmp(EXCEPTION_2, mystring)) {  except = 1; }
#else
#define EXCEPTIONS2 EXCEPTIONS1 
#endif

// etc
```

Again, not much better.

And you *really* shouldn't define macros with open `if`'s. It allows weird interactions like `if(cond) EXCEPTIONS1 else cout<<"error";` -- that won't do what you expect because `EXCEPTIONS1` is a plain `if` and will gobble up the `else` branch.

The typical way of writing macros with code blocks is to wrap the whole thing in a `do{...}while(0)` (note no ending `;`).

Answer (score 1):

Checkout the token stringification and concatenation section [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%5Fpreprocessor#Indirectly%5Fquoting%5Fmacro%5Farguments) 
It might help some. In general, it would seem easier to use your command line macro to populate a table and have a macro that simply expands to a loop that checks the successive entries of that table to set the except flag.

For instance, save the following as silly.c and compile with cc -DEX1=\"hello\"

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Except {
   const char* key;
   int flag;
};

struct Except table[] = {
#if defined(EX1)
   {EX1,1},
#endif
   {NULL,0}
};

#define CHECKEX(mys,rv)  { rv = 0;for(int i=0;table[i].key!=0;i++)      \
         if (strcmp(table[i].key,(mys))==0) \
            rv = 1; \
   }

int main()
{
   int rv;
   CHECKEX("hello",rv);
   if (rv)
      printf("Got an hello\n");
   else printf("Got nothing\n");
   return 0;
}
```

Simply add more "blocks" to the table as needed. Just a suggestion of course.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert a macro *argument* to a string:

```
#define STR(x)    #x

STR(hello)  -->  "hello"
```

And you can concatenate *string literals* by just writing them next to each other:

```
"123" "abc"  -->  "123abc"
```

Or create a macro:

```
#define CONCAT(a, b) a b

CONCAT("hello", " world!")  --> "hello world!"
```

Comment: I do not want to concatenate strings, I want to concatenate the input for the compiler

Comment: @RolandSeuhs: "How to concatenate/append substitution string". You should learn [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). Your question is far from being clear. And: strings _are_ input to the compiler. Egal!

Comment: What is that, you don't even bother to read past the question title and you're mocking the OP? Perhaps you should learn how to read and behave instead. Flagging this for moderator attention.

Comment: @Blindy: I did read further: "Is there a way to append a string to a preprocessor macro variable"

Answer (score -1):

You can use `##` to concatenate string to macros. Use an index and use the conditions only to set the index. Then at the end you can concatenate the index with your macro `EXCEPTION`. like,

define a macro like `#define append(name) name ## counter`

this will in turn give you `name` as `name1` if `counter` is 1

Now you can define different `append` macros to come with the result in a single variable `name`